# Failed to run "google_optimize_local_ssd" script: exec: "google_optimize_local_ssd":

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I deployed my application to Google compute engine through Container  Registry with container-optimized OS.
I didn't face any issues in several years. and also easier to redeploy to another instance and I can reproduce. The instance is managed by the scheduler, In the night time, start the instance, and stop in the morning.

but from last month, I faced the below error in the instance.
`Failed to run "google_optimize_local_ssd" script: exec: "google_optimize_local_ssd":`

I thought this was a storage issue, and I redeployed + made another instance through the container image. but still, I have the same issue, and no ideas for fix the issue.

I couldn't find a similar question or topic even if I searched.

[details]

- Instance Name:instance-1
- Machine: E2 medium
- region: asia-east1
- Deploy Container: original Docker image without volumn mount
- Boot Disk:Container Optimized OS 109 stable, Balanced persistent Disk, 100GB

[Erorr message in log]

```
GCE Agent Started (version 20230726.00)
WARNING 2023-11-04T18:26:55.966772772Z [resource.labels.instanceId: instance-1] Failed to run "google_optimize_local_ssd" script: exec: "google_optimize_local_ssd": executable file not found in $PATH
WARNING 2023-11-04T18:26:55.966902882Z [resource.labels.instanceId: instance-1] Failed to run "google_set_multiqueue" script: exec: "google_set_multiqueue": executable file not found in $PATH
INFO 2023-11-04T18:26:55.988737050Z [resource.labels.instanceId: instance-1] Instance ID changed, running first-boot actions
INFO 2023-11-04T18:26:56.362940682Z [resource.labels.instanceId: instance-1] OSConfig Agent (version 20230706.02) started.
DEFAULT 2023-11-04T18:26:56.363042052Z [resource.labels.instanceId: instance-1] {"logging.googleapis.com/diagnostic":{…}}
```

I also tried minimal dockerfile and confirmed that not working well...

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update && apt upgrade
```

Comment: Does your VM have local SSD? What is the Machine Type?

Comment: Yes, VM has local SSD.
I thought storage problem and increased volume from 10G to 100G. 
Type is Balanced persistent disk and Boot, read/write.

Comment: Why do you have a local SSD for a container? Your post is missing context to explain your setup and configuration.

Comment: THanks for your comment, Updated the details, local disk(Balanced persistent disk)is required for the instance, and container-optimized OS uses host's boot disk as default disk in my understanding.

Comment: A local SSD is not the same as a Persistent Disk. Shared E2 instances do not have local SSD. Which machine type and size have you deployed?

Comment: I see, so you meant running `google_optimize_local_ssd ` script is weird in the situtaion since I didn't enable local SSD and just have default Persistent Disk.

Comment: Oh, I updated above description. E2 medium, and Container Optimized OS 109 stable, Balanced persistent Disk, 100GB.

Comment: Yes, at this point, I think this is a Google issue and is probably harmless but I am not sure. Open a support ticket with Google Cloud Support.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I don't have premium support and can not submit a ticket... so, I 'll think another option.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I think this is more focus on your instance disk. You may want to check if your instance has enough space that can be used by your container. You can check this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/disks-and-filesystem) to understand file system inside container optimized os. To configure or change your boot disk size you can look into this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk).

Comment: I increased volume from 10G to 100G and it seems that I can confirm the exact same volume size from your suggested link..